# How to enable the aligning guides when using keyboard in Powerpoint 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have been using Powerpoint 2013, and love the guidelines when you try to align objects. But they seemed to turn on, only when using mouse to align them.

Any way to activate them when using keyboard for alignment?

Comment: you can use shortcuts to align the objects. Please refer the link http://www.shortcuttools.com/en/powerpoint_alignment_shortcuts_commands.html

Comment: thanks, but i knw some of those shortcuts. I was asking about the guides specifically.